# Passing array of parameters to object constructor

Tags: php, oop

How can I call a object constructor passing an array of parameters so that having:

```
$array = array($param1, $param2);
```

I'll be able to call

```
$abc = new Abc($param1, $param2);
```

considering that I don't know how many parameters could be set in the array.
Is there something like `call_object('Abc', array($param1, $param2))`?

Comment: why not just pass the array ? `new Abc($array)` ?

Comment: Maybe Jeff doesn't write/control those classes...

Comment: @JeffPigarelli perhaps if you had worded your question better or given more of an example you would not have got so many "incorrect" answers ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way is to use an array or object that stores the arguments and you just pass that array/object

Another way would be using Reflection ( https://www.php.net/Reflection ) using newInstanceArgs ( https://www.php.net/manual/de/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php )

Answer (score 21):

How about using ... (splat operator)?

```
$array = array($param1, $param2);
$abc = new Abc(...$array); // equal to: new Abc($param1, $param2)
```

[PHP 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php) is required.

Comment: Actually this should be marked as the right answer, because PHP 5.6 was released 5 years ago and isn't supported anymore. So **users are encouraged to use the latest stable PHP version** anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The ideal is to define your constructor to take an array.

If you can't do that, there is a possible workaround. If *all* parameters to the constructor are optional, you could do something like this with `call_user_func_array`:

```
$obj = new Abc;
call_user_func_array(array($obj, '__construct'), $array);
```

This results in your constructor being run twice: once with no parameters, and once with those in the array.  You'll have to decide whether this is suitable for your application.

Comment: Uhm! What if your Abc constructor need parameters? PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Abc::__construct(), 0 passed. So you cannot instanziate the object and then call the constructor. I'm missing something?

Comment: @guido "If *all* the parameters to the constructor are optional." This is hardly good practice: it's a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are able to modify your objects' constructors, a pattern like this isn't uncommon, but requires associative arrays as input:

```
class Abc {
  public $prop1;
  public $prop2;

  public function __construct($params) {
    if (is_array($params)) {
       $this->prop1 = isset($params['prop1']) ? $params['prop1'] : NULL;
       $this->prop2 = isset($params['prop2']) ? $params['prop2'] : NULL;
    }
  }
}

// Created as:
$params = array('prop1'=>12354, 'prop2'=>54321);
$abc = new Abc($params);
```

Comment: This won't work if you want to use a typed constructor.